# Reverse scrolling through the last argument of command in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh

When I want to see the last argument of a command in zsh, I can just press Alt+. However, sometimes I press it too much, and I would prefer to scroll back, like I can in fish with the keyboard shortcuts Alt+Up and Alt+Down. How can I do that in zsh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bash
# Create a function.
insert-next-word() { 
  # Tell `insert-last-word` to go forward (1), instead of backward (-1).
  zle insert-last-word -- 1 
}

# Create a widget that calls the function above.
zle -N insert-next-word

# Bind this widget to a keyboard shortcut.
bindkey '^[,' insert-next-word
```

Now, after you've pressed <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> one or more times, you can then press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> to cycle in the opposite direction.

Documentation: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-insert_002dlast_002dword

If you want, you can bind these commands to <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> instead:

```bash
# alt-↑
bindkey '^[^[OA' insert-last-word \
        '^[^[[A' insert-last-word

# alt-↓
bindkey '^[^[OB' insert-next-word \
        '^[^[[B' insert-next-word
```

In the key codes above, whether the second to last character should be `O` or `[` depends on how you've set up your terminal, but it doesn't hurt to bind both.

If neither version of the codes above work for you, then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, followed by the key combo you want to use, to see what key code your terminal actually outputs.

---

### Update

A more comprehensive solution is now available [as part of my plugin Zsh Edit](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-edit). In the Readme, the keybindings for this are named "Repeat word <direction>".